# Loss of point reputation what is the reason

Tags: discussion

I had reputation of 734 for about two weeks, today it is 709 with no explanation. When a person has earned the points they should not lose them.

Please explain what happened and can I get those points back?
Thanks

Answer (score 6):

Your answer [on this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/368693/wpa2-disconnects-at-intervals/368765#368765) was deleted. I assume it was accepted too, so that's 15 rep for the accepted status and 10 rep for the +1 score it had. That's the accounting side of it anyway.

The why is likely because the question was duplicate. Sometimes when a duplicate question is getting a lot of traffic we'll merge or purge the answers to facilitate an automatic redirect (so that people end up on the best possible question/answers), but I'm not the person who handled this.

I'll poke the right person to look in here.